# Unable to play Sprite Images with aspect ratio in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am trying to play sprite images on windows phone 8. But its not playing correctly, if the single sprite image is larger than screen dimensions. I try to reduce the image with aspect ratio by using rectangle and ImageBrush. Still I am facing the same problem. Please find the below scenario.

Scenario :
Sprite Width/Height : 22100 / 516

Single Sprite Width/Height : 850/516

Mobile Dimensions : 800/480

Could anyone can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understood your question, all you need to do is:

1. Create a `BitMapImage`, don't use `ImageBrush` or `Rectangle`..

   ```
   BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
   bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(imagePathOrUrl, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
   ```
2. I suggest you to add also this instruction to prevent memory issues:

   ```
   bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = imageWidth;
   ```
3. Add the `BitMapImage` to an `Image` control and set the `**Stretch**` property for the aspect ratio:

   ```
   Image img = new Image();
   img.Source=bitmapImage;
   img.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
   ```

`Stretch` property has also other values, so be sure to do some test with the other values to see what value adapts better to your needs.

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I tried the same thing what u have suggested. But its not working. I also tried to change all the Stretch properties. If we use the image, how can we do a sprite animation without using rectangle,Imagebrush ?

Comment: Can you please explain what kind of animation you want to achieve?

Comment: As I said in my first post we are having one sprite image( width : 22100 / Height :516). In that image we are having multiple images. For more info please find the below link   http://www.cnblogs.com/Jax/archive/2010/02/26/1673899.html.

Comment: Ok, got it! Have you tried to modify the `Stretch` property on `ImageBrush`? http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0470__Windows-Presentation-Foundation/ImageBrushStretchStyle.htm

Comment: Ys. I tried all Stretch properties.(FILL , UNIFORM, NONE , UNIFORM TO FILL). But unable to play exact sprite animation. Its not working.

Comment: I don't know man.. I'm sorry.. Have you considered to split the image manually and then change the image source inside the timer_tick event every time?